# Why i have to extract the file every time on google colab

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I was trying to build leaf disease detection on google Colab. I downloaded the dataset from Kaggle directory, it was in zip folder. So I unzip it at that time and built the model and saved it but next day when I opened that Collaboratory everything was gone. I have to extract the dataset again and train the model.

Is there any way so that I don't have to extract the dataset every time and train the model? Because it takes 1/2 hours to train and I don't have enough GPU to train it every day .

Comment: Mount your google drive, save there, re-mount the next time you start?

Comment: after re-mount  will the saved model and the unzipped dataset will be there ?? I dont have to unzipp it again?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state which framework you're using to build the model.

Here's some sample code using `keras`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Define a simple model
def create_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(512, activation="relu", input_shape=(784,)),
        keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
        keras.layers.Dense(10)
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer="adam",
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
    return model

# Create and train a new model instance.
model = create_model()
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=10)

# Save the entire model as a `.keras` zip archive.
model.save("simple_model.keras")

# Load a fresh Keras model from the .keras zip archive
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("simple_model.keras")
```

The low-level `tf.saved_model` API is available if you aren't using `keras`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Save a pretrained tensorflow model
tf.saved_model.save(pretrained_model, model_save_path)

# Load the model
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load(model_save_path)
```

See the online documentation for further information, [tf.saved_model API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model).

Comment: I am using tensorflow

Comment: I added a code snippet and a link to the documentation for the low-level API.